# IntelliJ IDEA - how to copy .java file as a resource?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am busy writing an integration test for a custom annotation processor. In order to do this I have a specific set of .java source files that I am running through javac in order to test my implementation. These are loaded by my test as a resource. This means that my source tree looks something like the following:

```
/src
  /test                            [test source root]
    /java
      MyIntegrationTest.java       [actual source code]
    /resources
      MyIntegrationClassFile.java  [should be treated as plain text]
```

With IntelliJ, it is possible to filter what files are copied as resources using the Compiler Settings. So I removed the filter for .java files.

However, for resources to be copied, they need to be in a marked source tree. I also have my resources folder marked as test sources (yes, this is weird).

**This is where the problem comes in:** If the .java files are in a source tree (in order to be copied as resources), they are automatically compiled. I do not want to compile these files (they may not compile).

I have tried adding the resources to the compiler exclude list (NOT excluding it from the project), but this also results the resources not being copied.

You cannot mark a .java file as plain text, as far as I know, even though this feature is documented for other file types.

How can one mark a .java file as plain content that should be copied and not compiled?

Comment: +1 I have a similar problem with a project I cannot change.  In this case it is code which doesn't compile by design to show it will be compiled dynamically correctly (or with expected errors)  IntelliJ doesn't like it at all.  Maven builds fine and copies the resources.

Comment: @PeterLawrey same, I am doing code generation that will result in the file compiling fine.

Comment: @tieTYT I have a Gradle build set up that works fine, but I would like to make it work with IntelliJ for convenience of debugging and just using the IDE test runner and so on.

EDIT: to clarify, for this specific problem, no. I am using the built-in IntelliJ build system

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked when I added the resource folder to the Compiler Exclude List.

Initial setup:

[image]

Rebuild project gives me this output:

[image]

Now I add the `src/test/resources` to the Compiler Exclude List:

[image]

After rebuild I have this in my output folder:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I will try reproduce this when I get home. Could you please also reference your setting for the resource exclude pattern? It is set by default to ignore .java files, but I assume you removed that.

Comment: I have tried this and my results differ from yours. I end up with `IntegrationTest.class` and `IntegrationTest.java`. The resources folder is still ignored. I see that you have a pom.xml. It might be working if you use Maven for the build. When I use a Gradle build everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Using Idea 2016.3.3, go to Project Structure>src>test>resources then right click on it and select TestResources.

Then add an exclusion rule to Settings>Build, Execution, Deployment> Compiler> Excludes for your resources folder.

Also remove .java extension from Settings>Build, Execution, Deployment> Compiler>Resource patterns (you've already done this as I can see).

It works!